# JSF URLs rewriting

Tags: jsf, url-rewriting

I try to use ‘rewrite’ (http://ocpsoft.org/rewrite/ )in my JSF application.

All is fine, I've created rule:

```
.addRule(Join.path("/profile/{pagename}-{id}/").to("/profile/{pagename}.xhtml?id={id}"))
```

All works fine, for example, when I go to the /profile/viewpoll-101/, I see correct page with poll with id = 101. So, now I want to get user friendly links in h:link jsf elements. I'm trying this:

```
<h:link outcome="/profile/viewpoll-#{poll.id}/">
    #{poll.title}
</h:link>
```

But link is not active...

So, how can I get user friendly links in h:link?

Thanks!

Answer (score 5):

There's no way to do it using rewrite, only with Prettyfaces. With rewrite you have to specify the JSF identifier.

> PrettyFaces shipped with a special JSF component that simplified creating links to mapped URLs. However JSF 2.0 introduced h:link, which works fine for creating such links. Rewrite doesn’t include any special JSF component. It is recomended to use the standard JSF component for rendering links.
>
> Using h:link for creating links to Rewrite URLs is very easy. Just use the URL you configured as the to part of the Join for the outcome. If the URL contains parameters, set their value using f:param.

```xhtml
<h:link outcome="/customer-details.jsf">
  <f:param name="id" value="123"/>
  Show details
</h:link>
```

In **JSF 2**, with implicit navigation, you could use this to access */customer-details.jsp* or */customer-details.xhtml*:

```
<h:link outcome="/customer-details">
  <f:param name="id" value="123"/>
  Show details
</h:link>
```

**See also:**

- [Creating JSF links with rewrite](http://ocpsoft.org/rewrite/docs/migration/prettyfaces3#_creating_links)
- [Implicit Navigation in JSF 2](http://balusc.blogspot.com.es/2011/09/communication-in-jsf-20.html#ImplicitNavigation)

Comment: But I don't map this url through the PrettyFaces. I map this urls through the Rewrite ( http://ocpsoft.org/rewrite/examples/ )

Comment: I just noticed it ;-) Updated my answer according to the docs.

Comment: If the resource name needs to be "customer-details-123" then customer-details.xhtml?id=123 is not really satisfactory. You're using knowledge of the page to which the rule rewrites, which may work but is not nice. I think it's a bug in Rewrite/PrettyFaces. It should validate the resource name as used in the outcome (JSF calls various plug-ins for this, of which PrettyFaces should be one)